# How to handle this exception properly?

Tags: c#, .net, exception, user-interface, dll

I'm still a novice programmer(from C++) and I am creating a GIU which displays a Tag from a running software. The purpose is to display the tag properties `Description` and `Eng Units` . I have been given 2 dlls InTouchDataAccess and NDde.
I've read on exception handeling and the best idea I've seen was this one:
[Create a Validate function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6681514/c-sharp-catch-exception)

which I did. But the program does no enter the function, I goes straigh into the catch block of my `SelectButton_Click` fct.

**TagBrowser.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using IOM.InTouchDataAccess;

namespace InTouchTagBrowser
{
    public partial class InTouchTagBrowser : Form
    {
        public string tagName;
        public string description;
        public string engUnits;

        public InTouchTagBrowser()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void TagBrowser_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }

        private void SelectButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                tagName = tagNameBox.Text;
                InTouchDdeWrapper inTouchWrapper = new InTouchDdeWrapper();
                inTouchWrapper.Initialize();

                TagDotField tagDotField = new TagDotField(tagName);

                string value = inTouchWrapper.Read(tagName);

                if (EngValidate(inTouchWrapper.Read(tagDotField.EngUnits)) != 0)
                {
                    engUnits = inTouchWrapper.Read(tagDotField.EngUnits);
                }

                else
                {
                    engUnits = "N/A";
                }

                if (inTouchWrapper.Read(tagDotField.Description) != "")
                {
                    description = inTouchWrapper.Read(tagDotField.Description);
                }
                else
                {
                    description = "N/A";
                }

                descriptionlbl.Text = description;
                englbl.Text = engUnits;
                valuelbl.Text = value;
            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Source);
                MessageBox.Show(ex.HelpLink);
                MessageBox.Show(ex.StackTrace);
            }
        }

        private void WriteButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                if (tagName == "")
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Please enter a tag!");
                }
                else
                {
                    string inputValue = ValueBox.Text;
                    InTouchDdeWrapper inTouchWrapperWriter = new InTouchDdeWrapper();
                    inTouchWrapperWriter.Initialize();

                    TagDotField tagWriter = new TagDotField(inputValue);
                    inTouchWrapperWriter.Write(tagName, inputValue);
                    valuelbl.Text = inputValue;
                }
            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
            finally
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Tag change successfull");
            }
        }

        public int EngValidate(string engString)
        {
            string exception;
            int x;

            try
            {
                InTouchDdeWrapper inTouchWrapper = new InTouchDdeWrapper();
                inTouchWrapper.Initialize();
                TagDotField tagDotField = new TagDotField(tagName);
                engString = inTouchWrapper.Read(tagDotField.EngUnits);

                x = 1;
            }
            catch (Exception msg)
            {
                exception = msg.ToString();
                if (exception == "")
                    x = 1;
                else
                    x = 0;
            }

            return x;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: By right, it wouldn't go straight into the exception block. 1. What was the excpetion? 2. Can you try to use F11 to step into instead of step over.

Comment: Yes I did Step Into, and It did Step in. It went straight to the catch block. The exception says **The client failed to request « View|Tagname! $TimeString.EngUnits.”**

Comment: If you are debugging, you can break when an exception is thrown as well as when it is caught. (VS2008) On the Debug menu, Exceptions, tick the Thrown box for "Common Language Runtime Exceptions".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're declaring a variable `engString` for your method which you don't actually use. Additionally, the way you set this variable reads from the wrapper which can cause an exception (which is then catched by the outer catch block). A better approach would be to declare such a method reading only once:

```
public bool TryRead(InTouchDdeWrapper wrapper, string prop, out string value) 
{
  try 
  {
    value = wrapper.Read(prop);
    return true;
  }
  catch (Exception e)
  {
    value = null;
    return false;
  }  
}
```

Called like this:

```
InTouchDdeWrapper wrapper = new InTouchDdeWrapper();
wrapper.Initialize();

TagDotField field = new TagDotField(tagName);

string engUnits;

if (!TryRead(wrapper, field.EngUnits, out engUnits)) 
{
  engUnits = "N/A";
}
```

I hope you get the idea of this pattern. You instantiate (and initialize) a lot of classes over and over again in your code where it would be better to just have one wrapper, one field, etc ... and to read the values only once. Additionally, you shouldn't make use of return codes in C#, that's what exceptions are for.

Comment: God, Thank you! How do you manage to read and understand foreign code so quickly and deal with object so well? I've noticed that a lot of good programmers here do this too.

Comment: Glad that I could help. With some experience it's easier to dig into foreign code, because you know most of the principles, frameworks and patterns. Look at the piece of code you've posted in one or two months, and you'll see, how much you've learned :)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to adjust `global  treatment for exception`

You need to handle the `System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadException event` for Windows Forms.

Link : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.threadexception.aspx

Nota : you delete all realised try-catch in your forms, and you set just one treatment